# Python no OPENSSL_Applink

Tags: python-2.7, x509, pyopenssl

I am trying to create a x.509 certificate but I keep encountering the error *`OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FF944EF2000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink`* as shown below. I am and not sure of how to proceed.

[image]

When I searched around, I found someone suggesting the use of "BIO" to open the file, but I don't know how to do that... Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import time
from M2Crypto import X509, EVP, RSA, ASN1

KeyLength=2048

CAName='TS.CN'               
ServerName='CF.CN'

CAKeyFile='ca.key'
CACerFile='ca.cer'
ServerKeyFile='server.key'
ServerCerFile='Server.cer'


def mk_ca_issuer():
    """
    Our default CA issuer name.
    """
    issuer = X509.X509_Name()
    issuer.C = 'CN'
    issuer.CN = CAName
    issuer.ST = 'TS'
    issuer.L = 'TS'
    issuer.O = 'TS'
    issuer.OU = 'TS'
    return issuer


def mk_cert_valid(cert, days=365):
    """
    Make a cert valid from now and til 'days' from now.
    Args:
       cert -- cert to make valid
       days -- number of days cert is valid for from now.
    """
    t = long(time.time())
    now = ASN1.ASN1_UTCTIME()
    now.set_time(t)
    expire = ASN1.ASN1_UTCTIME()
    expire.set_time(t + days * 24 * 60 * 60)
    cert.set_not_before(now)
    cert.set_not_after(expire)


def mk_request(bits, cn='CF.CN'):
    """
    Create a X509 request with the given number of bits in they key.
    Args:
      bits -- number of RSA key bits
      cn -- common name in the request
    Returns a X509 request and the private key (EVP)
    """
    pk = EVP.PKey()
    x = X509.Request()
    rsa = RSA.gen_key(bits, 65537, lambda: None)
    pk.assign_rsa(rsa)
    x.set_pubkey(pk)
    name = x.get_subject()
    name.C = 'CN'
    name.CN = cn
    name.ST = 'TS'
    name.O = 'TS'
    name.OU = 'TS'
    x.sign(pk,'sha1')
    return x, pk


def mk_cacert():
    """
    Make a CA certificate.
    Returns the certificate, private key and public key.
    """
    req, pk = mk_request(KeyLength)
    pkey = req.get_pubkey()
    cert = X509.X509()
    cert.set_serial_number(1)
    cert.set_version(2)
    mk_cert_valid(cert)
    cert.set_issuer(mk_ca_issuer())
    cert.set_subject(cert.get_issuer())
    cert.set_pubkey(pkey)
    cert.add_ext(X509.new_extension('basicConstraints', 'CA:TRUE'))
    cert.add_ext(X509.new_extension('subjectKeyIdentifier', cert.get_fingerprint()))
    cert.sign(pk, 'sha1')
    return cert, pk, pkey


def mk_cert():
    """
    Make a certificate.
    """
    cert = X509.X509()
    cert.set_serial_number(2)
    cert.set_version(2)
    mk_cert_valid(cert)
    cert.add_ext(X509.new_extension('nsComment', 'SSL sever'))
    return cert


def mk_casigned_cert():
    """
    Create a CA cert + server cert + server private key.
    """
    # unused, left for history.
    cacert, pk1, _ = mk_cacert()
    cert_req, pk2 = mk_request(KeyLength, cn=ServerName)
    cert = mk_cert()
    cert.set_issuer(cacert.get_issuer())
    cert.set_subject(cert_req.get_subject())
    cert.set_pubkey(cert_req.get_pubkey())
    cert.sign(pk1, 'sha1')
    return cacert, cert,pk1, pk2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cacert, cert, pk1,pk2 = mk_casigned_cert()

    with open(CACerFile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(cacert.as_pem())
    with open(ServerCerFile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(cert.as_pem())
    with open(CAKeyFile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(pk1.as_pem(None))
    with open(ServerKeyFile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(pk2.as_pem(None))

    # Sanity checks...
    cac = X509.load_cert(CACerFile)
    print cac.verify(), cac.check_ca()
    cc = X509.load_cert(ServerCerFile)
    print cc.verify(cac.get_pubkey())
```

Comment: This will happen if the C runtime version OpenSSL is using is different to the one used by Python. Are you using a 32-bit version of Python with a 64-bit version of OpenSSL? Or vice-versa?

Comment: What version of OpenSSL are you using (possibly a more up to date version will help)?

Comment: The OpenSSL is openssl-1.0.2l(don't know 64-bit or 32-bit). And the version of Python is python-2.7.13 win64.

Comment: Now I install the OpenSSL-1.0.2lWin64, but the problem still exits. What should I do?

Comment: Using of "BIO" instead of reading directly from file solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenSSL FAQ under the topic [I've compiled a program under Windows and it crashes](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG2):

> This is usually because you've missed the comment in INSTALL.W32. Your
>   application must link against the same version of the Win32 C-Runtime
>   against which your openssl libraries were linked. The default version
>   for OpenSSL is /MD - "Multithreaded DLL".
>
> If you are using Microsoft Visual C++'s IDE (Visual Studio), in many
>   cases, your new project most likely defaulted to "Debug
>   Singlethreaded" - /ML. This is NOT interchangeable with /MD and your
>   program will crash, typically on the first BIO related read or write
>   operation.
>
> For each of the six possible link stage configurations within Win32,
>   your application must link against the same by which OpenSSL was
>   built. If you are using MS Visual C++ (Studio) this can be changed by:
>
> ```
> 1. Select Settings... from the Project Menu.
> 2. Select the C/C++ Tab.
> 3. Select "Code Generation from the "Category" drop down list box
> 4. Select the Appropriate library (see table below) from the "Use
> run-time library" drop down list box.  Perform this step for both
> your debug and release versions of your application (look at the
> top left of the settings panel to change between the two)
>
> Single Threaded           /ML        -  MS VC++ often defaults to
>                                         this for the release
>                                         version of a new project.
> Debug Single Threaded     /MLd       -  MS VC++ often defaults to
>                                         this for the debug version
>                                         of a new project.
> Multithreaded             /MT
> Debug Multithreaded       /MTd
> Multithreaded DLL         /MD        -  OpenSSL defaults to this.
> Debug Multithreaded DLL   /MDd
> ```
>
> Note that debug and release libraries are NOT interchangeable. If you
>   built OpenSSL with /MD your application must use /MD and cannot use
>   /MDd.
>
> As per 0.9.8 the above limitation is eliminated for .DLLs. OpenSSL
>   .DLLs compiled with some specific run-time option [we insist on the
>   default /MD] can be deployed with application compiled with different
>   option or even different compiler. But there is a catch! Instead of
>   re-compiling OpenSSL toolkit, as you would have to with prior
>   versions, you have to compile small C snippet with compiler and/or
>   options of your choice. The snippet gets installed as
>   /include/openssl/applink.c and should be either added to
>   your application project or simply #include-d in one [and only one] of
>   your application source files. Failure to link this shim module into
>   your application manifests itself as fatal "no OPENSSL_Applink"
>   run-time error. An explicit reminder is due that in this situation
>   [mixing compiler options] it is as important to add CRYPTO_malloc_init
>   prior first call to OpenSSL.

Comment: I use IDLE(Python GUI)...What should I do?